# how to loop in python API with restriction on LIMIT and can provide offset

Tags: python, api

I am new to python API. I need help in calling API data from python where we have limit of 20000 rows per page. Yes off course we can apply offset. But I am looking for a loop to extract complete data. Below is the python script. Sry I am new and not having much experience in writing the script.

````
querystring1 = {"limit":"20000","month":"122021","offset":"20000","dateformat":"X"}    
querystring2 = {"limit":"20000","month":"122021","offset":"40000","dateformat":"X"}    
querystring3 = {"limit":"20000","month":"122021","offset":"60000","dateformat":"X"}    

response = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=querystring)    
response1 = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=querystring1)    
response2 = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=querystring2)    
response3 = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=querystring3)    

data = json.loads(response.text)    
data1 = json.loads(response1.text)    
data2 = json.loads(response2.text)    
data3 = json.loads(response3.text)    

db = pd.DataFrame(data)    
db1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)    
db2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)    
db3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)    

month = 'DEC2021_UAE'    

csvdata = db.to_csv(month+'_1.csv',index=True,encoding="utf-8")    
csvdata1 = db1.to_csv(month+'_2.csv',index=False,encoding="utf-8")    
csvdata2 = db2.to_csv(month+'_3.csv',index=False,encoding="utf-8")    
csvdata3 = db3.to_csv(month+'_4.csv',index=False,encoding="utf-8")```   

at the end I have 4 different csv files however I want to able to loop through the API and should extract the data in file rather then 4 files.

Any Help Please...
````

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your `offset`'s, make an API call and store the data and then combine the DataFrames in one operation using `pd.concat`.

```
offsets = ["20000", "40000", "60000"]
api_data = []

for offset in offsets:
    qs = {"limit":"20000","month":"122021","offset":offset,"dateformat":"X"}
    response = requests.request("GET", BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=qs)
    data = resp.json()
    api_data.append(data)

month = 'DEC2021_UAE'
csv_data = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(data) for data in api_data), ignore_index=True)
csv_data.to_csv(month)
```

Comment: Hi @gold_cy... I tried the above script. It is only downloading 30,000 rows with duplicate and when removed the duplicate rows it comes to 10,000 rows. We have around 50,000 rows for current month. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: the duplicates isn’t because of the code, it’s whatever logic you showed in your first attempt. I simply changed your code to run in a loop.